# How to set 'Fade-In' animations by React.js

Tags: css, reactjs

I would like you to give me any ideas for my trouble.

Currently, I am now creating a web page with 'Fade-In' animations, meaning that specific elements ( tags in my case) would come up from the bottom of the page.
(Please see a picture to show my image of 'Fade-In')

[image]

However, this does not work well.
[image]

Here are files of React.js (excluding unrelated files)

About.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import MyProfile from './AboutME/MyProfile'
import MyCareer from './AboutME/MyCareer'
import History from './AboutME/History'


const About = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <MyProfile />
      <MyCareer />
      <History />
    </>
  )
}



export default About
```

History.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import Resume from './Resume'


const History = () => {
  return (
  <>
    <div className='history'>
        <Resume />
    </div>
    <div id='closing'>
        *To improve my skills further, I currently learn about React.js, Django, and Python, GoLang, and so on.
    </div>
    
  </>
  )
}

export default History
```

Resume.jsx (this has a fade-in animation script)

```
import React from 'react'


const Resume = props => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className='jobs'>
        <h3>Backend Developer</h3>
        <p>2023.4 - 2023.11</p>
        <p>Insurance Firm's Project</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Designed a new Oracle database.</p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Coding on PL/SQL and CShell scripts.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='jobs'>
        <h3>RPA Programmar</h3>
        <p>2023.7 - 2023.10</p>
        <p>Local Donation System Project</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>With UiPath, automated operations to collect specific datas of each municipality,
                    such as its monthly donations and reviews from donators on its return gifts.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>And put them into an Excel sheet.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='jobs'>
        <h3>Consultant and Engineer</h3>
        <p>2022.1 - 2023.3</p>
        <p>Communication Career Firm's Project</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Researched and analyzed client's datas to boost their current business.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Further developed existing tools for operations.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='jobs'>
        <h3>RPA Programmar and Translator</h3>
        <p>2019.7 - 2021.12</p>
        <p>Communication Service Project</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>As a RPA engineer, worked for requirement definitions, <br></br>
                    detail designs, coding, UT・IT, and follow-ups.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Automated a procedure to validate a few kind of application forms and put them<br></br>
                     into official one
                    to submit to the Japanese goverment.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Along with RPA works, wrote a list of test items for <br></br>newly developed functions of
                    client's systems. Sometimes translate documents to share with overseas members.
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div className='jobs'>
        <h3>Helpdesk and Translator</h3>
        <p>2018.4 - 2019.3</p>
        <p>Security Firm's Asset Management</p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <p>Dealt with users' inquiries on their troubles with PCs or accessories.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>Set up PCs for newly hired staff members.
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <p>
                    Mediate end users and overseas vendor staff members
                     in English via face-to-face or emails.
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

let els = document.querySelectorAll('jobs');

els.forEach(function(fadeIn) {
  let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let offset = fadeIn.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    let scroll = window.scrollY;
    
    if(scroll > offset - windowHeight + 250){
       fadeIn.classList.add('active');
    }
  })
})

export default Resume
```

index.css (excluding unrelated codes)

```
div.jobs{
  padding: 24px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(30px);
    transition: opacity 1.5s, transform 1s;
}
.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

Please give me any information.  Thanks in advance so much.